# Searching a certaing string depending on the keywods in string and finding out labels where the keyword belongs

Tags: php, jquery, search, full-text-search, search-engine

I want to develop a mechanism for search, but I have some **requirements** for it.
I am not getting where should I start.

*For example*
I have to search this string

```
stringToSearch = 'I have to search something';
```

For that I am going to add some ***labels*** to certain ***keywords*** at start.
suppose ***Messi*** will come under ***football***,
and ***Rain*** will come under ***Weather***
and ***Search*** will come in ***Search Engine***, ***Google***,...

Like that so I have Labels for keywords in short and it could be possible that one keyword is in multiple labels.

Now when I am searching some string I do have to calculate best **labels** for it and I want to do it on the basis of criteria mentioned below.

1. I will add keywords to labels on the basis of user answering a search string belongs to which label (User u can take here as a answering agents who will chose their labels so that question of particular labels come to them)
2. Every time keywords match will be counted.
3. If more than one keywords in a string belongs to one labels then select that labels as relevant one.

I have just an idea.

I am good with PHP,Jquery. Some one suggested me to not code it in PHP.
Please suggest me the technology

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) You split the string at spaces into an array ([explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php), ...)

b) You use [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) or [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to have a callback check if the entry corresponds to a label and then replace the value with the label or add the label as an entry to the returned array. If a word doesnt have label you delete it or leave it out.

c) Then you have [array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) count the labels

Comment: Thanks so you are recommending PHP to do this or should i go with jquery to make it more dynamic

Comment: jQuery's realm is solely restriced to DOM-manipulation and UI-development ... no data processing. This would be ONE way to do it.